# how to put video view and webview in fragement and retain state of orientation changes

Tags: android

I am new to fragment can anybody tell how to put video view and webview in fragement and retain state of orientation changes in android.can anybody give example

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to add a configChanges property to your FragmentActivity declared in your AndroidManifest.xml like this:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".YourFragmentActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation" />
```

That should solve your problem.